# How to use @NotNull

Tags: hibernate, jpa, tomcat

I don't know how to use @NotNull.I write @NotNull,but I can't get message in Tomcat or error message.

I used @NotEmpty.but this cause Tomcat falling.

```
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "title", length = 255, nullable = false)
  private String title;
```

I expect Tomcat show error log,or webpage will show error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print a message if you want to have some sort of logs for the validation rule being violated.

Example: This class[Foo] uses @NotNull and @Size to declare those validation rules.

```
package foos;
import java.util.List;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class Foo {

@NotNull
@Size(min=5, message="Name must be at least 5 characters long")
private String name;

@Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 item")
private List<String> items;

}
```

Comment: Sorry,I don't know how to use lombok.I add lombok(version:1.16.20) to pom.xml.And set null on title,but I can't see error message

Comment: Lombok is irrelevant to this question. It’s just so I that I don’t have to define setters, getters, toString and to hashcode. How r u testing the validation rule?

Comment: Thank you.I will be careful not to ask irrelevant questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is constraint at Hibernate side, and it won’t be showing on web UI, you can catch the exception and show it on UI.

https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/